# static library in xcode 4.4.1

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I need to make a static library in xcode of my project , so that i can use it other project by linking it, I have through the tutorial of making static library on icodeblog.com
I have some of the following questions ??

1)- Wat does a library actually contain ? does it contain compiled version of  both the .h and .m files of the project or just of the .m files ?

2)-If It contains compiled .h and .m files , then why do we need to add .h files in the project in which we are using the  static library(By using the copy headers option)

3)-Even after adding .h files to that project , then why does the following error comes ?
"$OBJC_CLASS_NAME appeared in CLASS.o" not found ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for problem...it is because libraries cannot be tested on Simulator

need to test on devices only .. 
thats why . i was getting the error mentioned in "3)"

Comment: Could you please elaborate, I use libraries both on device and simulator with success.

Comment: I tried on simulator , it didnt work ,but when tested in devices it works fine

Answer (score 1):

To make a static library I heartily recommend [this approach](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework)

To answer your questions:

1. It contains object code for the contents of your .h and .m files.
2. The header files lets you use the code in the library. If there are no header files, your project would not know what to call.
3. If you are using the correct header files, this indicates to me that you are not linking against the correct library or that the library is incorrectly built. Is the guide you have been using correct? The guide I am pointing to works for me and many others.

Comment: Correct, one of the pieces of that framework is a static library.

Comment: Will it work if i just take the .a file from the framework and then drag it into my required project....or is it that the "headers" folder is also needed to be dragged into my project ...??

Comment: It won't work if you just use the .a file. But if you then include the needed headers it should work.